# Is there a better way to make a user profile tab using a view?

Tags: views, users

I have created a question node type using CCK and would like to show all of the questions which users create on a tab on their profile page.

The way I have done this feels a little indirect. I have:

1. Created a view which lists all of a user's questions and made a block to display it.
2. Configured the block so that it only displays on the right path ("user/*/questions").
3. Created an entry in hook_menu for this path. Used a page callback which calls a function which creates an empty page (see below).

Is there a more direct way to do this by, e.g., attaching the view directly to the profile page?

The code in `hook_menu()` is:

```
$items['user/%/questions'] = array(
  'title'            => 'Your Questions',
  'description'      => 'User Questions',
  'page callback' => 'answers_blank_page',
  'access arguments'  => array('create question content'),
  'type'     => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 9,
);
```

The page callback is simply:

```
function answers_blank_page () {
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any need to use a custom module for this: The Views module already allows you to associate a URL to a view and make the view appears as a menu tab.

The following screenshots are for Views 7.x-3.x-dev, but the settings are present also in previous versions of the module.
Under "Page settings," there are two options: "Path" and "Menu." The screenshots shows the settings used for a view implemented by a third-party module (the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module), whose view is shown as menu tab.

> [image: path settings]

> [image: menu settings]

Comment: Just wanted to say "thanks" ... while it took a little while for me to get back to this, this solution worked great. (It turns out I even ended up wanting to create a sub-menu and the same set of ideas here worked for using Views built-in capabilities to make that). Much simpler than what I had.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new page view, and then configure it to provide a menu item, specifically a tab, at path user/%/questions.

Answer (score 1):

It should work just by creating a page display, setting the path appropriately; no need to do the tricky steps you used.

Edit: you must also specify a menu item for the display.